# What's the Last Item on Shadows Shopping List?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, american-gods

In [American Gods](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1898069/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) [episode 2](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5062946/?ref_=ttep_ep2), the protagonist Shadow Moon is sent shopping by Mr. Wednesday.

He is given a shopping list that is quite revealing, among other items we see in the episode, '*Ear Muffs*' and '*Clipboard*' are listed which reveals that a specific and iconic scene from the book will soon take place, and almost certainly in episode 3, however I cannot decipher the last item on the list, can anyone see what it might be? Possibly the third word is 'grey'?

[image]

Comment: So... 2 cell phones is on his list of things to buy and then Mr. Wednesday complains when he buys them and throws them out the window of the car? That's... odd. I can't remember from the episode but Mr. Wednesday gave him the list, right... That's his writing, not Shadow's?

Comment: ^ Yes. This is almost certainly a mistake, but that would be a different question :)

Comment: Yeah... Apparently [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/americangods/comments/6a270q/the_shopping_list_mr_wednesday_gave_shadow_says_2/) is confused about it, too. I don't suppose the book tells us what the list is?

Comment: Is it the vodka? Doesn't he buy two bottles of Vodka? That doesn't seem to be on the list. Also seems to be missing the binoculars.

Comment: I thought about that, but I don't see anything resembling vodka or booze. The first item on the list (not included in the screenshot) is "Highliters (pack)" which is also rather mysterious to me.

Comment: And no, in the book Shadow does not go shopping :)

Comment: I would ask that question if I wasn't generally opposed to "did I find a plot hole" questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To me it appears to say "shirt, sweater, grey pants", but I have no proof or any way to back this up. Sorry!

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I think we may be able to confirm on Sunday. Thanks.

Comment: While not entirely confirmed by the episode, I still believe you are right. Shirt, sweater, grey pants, clipboard and earmuffs are described in the narrative as his "bank robbery outfit" and any lack of these items in the scene seems to me a continuity error on par with the two cellphones.Also, it looks right to me by reading the partial words on the list.